# What's the purpose of daemonize like this?

Tags: c, daemon

```
ngx_int_t ngx_daemon(ngx_log_t *log)
{
    int  fd;

    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_EMERG, log, ngx_errno, "fork() failed");
        return NGX_ERROR;

    case 0:
        break;

    default:
        exit(0);
    }
```

It seems pointless to me,as it only changes the pid,nothing else.

What's the benifit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process becomes detached from the terminal so that when the user that started it quits his session, the process remains running.

Daemonizing is not only about the fork, it involves calling `setsid(2)` in the child process that detaches the process from the controlling terminal. If you run `ps` you can see such processes marked with a `?` in the tty column.

Also, when you start a daemon it returns the control to the shell right after the fork, rather than the shell having to wait for the process to terminate.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev,do you mean the shell will still wait there if `setsid` is not called after `fork`?

Comment: The shell will not wait if `setsid` is not called, but the process will terminate after the user that started it logs out, and usually that's not desirable with daemons.

Comment: Only calling `setsid` will detach the process from the controlling tty, but will not return the control to the shell.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev ,if I run a program **A** that calls `setsid()` but not `fork()`,then if I close my shell,will that programe **A** survive?

Comment: Yes, try typing `setsid sleep 100` in your shell, close it, open it again and see how the process is still there.

Comment: @cpuer: Note also that the `setsid()` may fail if you do not fork first - forking guarantees that the child is not a process group leader.

Answer (score 1):

What this does is break the parent-child link. The parent who is waiting on the child will stop waiting because the child will spawn the daemon and then exit.

Comment: but this process doesn't have a parent so far.

Comment: @cpuer: The parent is the shell or `init` or whomever runs the command to start the daemon. The command to start the daemon becomes the child. The child spawns the daemon and exits, satisfying the parent's wait.

Answer (score 1):

The process also becomes the 'process group leader'.  See this SO answer which contains much more detail:

[Create a daemon with double-fork in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740308/create-a-daemon-with-double-fork-in-ruby)